# Gitweb document root with gitolite

Tags: gitolite, git

I'm on Mac OsX, trying to host my own git server. I've got gitolite running perfectly.

However, I have a folder called "`git`" in my `Sites` directory, such that visiting http://git.example.com points to that directory.

How can I get Gitweb's document root to point to my gitolite "`repositories`" folder in `/Users/me/repositories/`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a [`gitweb.conf.pl` file (like this one)](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitweb/gitweb.conf.pl.tpl) which:

- will be called by gitweb (if that file exists and defines a `export_auth_hook` sub, `gitweb.cgi` calls it)
- will specify where the git repos are
- will call gitolite

That would include:

```
$ENV{GL_REPO_BASE_ABS} = "$ENV{HOME}/repositories";
$export_auth_hook = sub {
    my $repo = shift;
    my $user = $ENV{GL_USER};
    # gitweb passes us the full repo path; so we strip the beginning
    # and the end, to get the repo name as it is specified in gitolite conf
    return unless $repo =~ s/^\Q$projectroot\E\/?(.+)\.git$/$1/;

    # check for (at least) "R" permission
    my $ret = &access( $repo, $user, 'R', 'any' );
    my $res = $ret !~ /DENIED/;
    return ($ret !~ /DENIED/);
};
```

With [`access()` being a function of `gitolite/src/lib/Gitolite/Conf/Load.pm`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/lib/Gitolite/Conf/Load.pm#L68-116).

Your `httpd.conf` would then call the `gitweb.cgi` script [like in this one](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/apache/env.conf.tpl#L49).

Comment: I'm still having the mismatch between the listing at http://git.jshawl.com/ and the the "txt" version at http://git.jshawl.com/?a=project_index I pasted this into a file /etc/gitweb.conf.pl

Comment: @jessh what version of Git are you using?

Comment: the most recent version `git version 1.7.7.5 (Apple Git-26)`

Comment: @jessh ok, just checkng if the gitweb was a recent one (and it isn't really, but I don't know if that matters). Does your `project.list` includes *all* repos, including `gitolite-admin`?

Comment: That's the thing!! I have no `project.list`. How do I get one?!

Comment: @jessh It should be generated automatically by the gitolite installation. Another thing, the script automatically called by gitweb (if it exists) is actually `gitweb_config.perl` (https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitweb/gitweb_config.perl), which in turns calls my custom `gitweb.conf.pl`.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was missing my project.list, I created it myself. Then I chmod -r 755'ed the whole repositories directory. Working now!

Comment: So you didn't need the `gitweb_conf.perl` addon?

Comment: I didn't. Bizarre right?

Comment: So, is it really working? Meaning, if you declare in gitolite a repo as not visible for a certain user, will that user actually see or not said repo through your gitweb?

Comment: It seems similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041578/gitweb-404-no-projects-found/12043363#comment16182724_12043363

Comment: @VonC: A mystery to me - similar thing here: The projects.list exists, is accessible, and so the gitweb page shows "no such projects" (but not the 404 msg). At the same time, clicking the <txt> link in the lower right displays a projects.list with the two repos I selected to be public.  Now I'm hesitant to install additional perl scripts and an apache redirect rule if it turns out that that's not really required.

Comment: @cfi I understand, but I always had to add that script in order to plug gitweb into gitolite