# Missing repos in gitweb

Tags: gitolite, git

Something crazy is happening to me.

If you visit http://git.jshawl.com/, you'll see a single repo "testing.git", though if you click on "TXT" in the lower right corner, you can see another repo that is there "wordpress-theme"

Also, I know there repo is there because I can clone it
`git clone git@git.jshawl.com/boilerplates/wordpress-theme`

what gives?

Here's a little more background info on my setup:

git.jshawl.com is hosted on Mac OS X, in the directory "/Users/git/repositories" (this was setup when I installed gitolite), I've got a VHOST that points to this directory. I also dropped my gitweb.cgi file into that directory.

My permissions on both the boilerplates directory and the wordpress-theme directory are 755 (rwxr-xr-x)

Comment: Any comment/feedback regarding my previous answer? (http://serverfault.com/a/419109/783)

Comment: Does the http setup described below works a bit better than the gitweb?

Answer (score 0):

Note: gitweb isn't for cloning.
It is for browsing.

Should you want to clone, you would have to define a custom root in your apache server config in order to call the gitolite-shell, with the GIT_HTTP_BACKEND defined and pointing to the `git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend` cgi script (shipped with git) which allows for clone/push/pull over the web.

Here is an extract of what that would look like (see the [full version here](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/apache/env.conf.tpl#L95-L112))

```
# GitHttp on @PORT_HTTP_HGIT@
Listen @PORT_HTTP_HGIT@
<VirtualHost @FQN@:@PORT_HTTP_HGIT@>
ServerName @FQN@
ServerAlias @HOSTNAME@
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT @H@/repositories
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
SetEnv GITOLITE_HTTP_HOME @H@
ScriptAlias /hgit/ @H@/gitolite/bin/gitolite-shell/
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_BACKEND "@H@/usr/local/apps/git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend"
<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Location /hgit>
```

In your case, it looks like the gitolite filter I decribed in my [previous answer](https://serverfault.com/a/419109/783) isn't completely in place. Just calling gitweb.cgi isn't enough.

It will display only the projects listed in your `project.list` file, but without any gitolite filter, the `TXT` link displays all the .git bare repo in your `repositories` directory.