# gitolite.conf - Write and rewind permissions (W+) are being lost everytime a git push occurs

Tags: redmine, gitolite

At my company, we are adopting Redmine as the support tool for our software projects management. Since we were using git for SCM, I've installed and configured the [Redmine git hosting plugin](https://github.com/ericpaulbishop/redmine_git_hosting) and gitolite, since its a plugin requirement.

In the plugin configuration, I selected to automatically create a new repo everytime a new project is created and it seems to work just fine. After the project creation, I configure the users who should have access to the repo and the desired permissions for them through the gitolite.conf file.

However, a weird problem is occurring: everytime a push some commits into the remote repo, the W+ permissions are lost., being my user only able to read access to the repo.

Some useful information (I hope) about my system configuration:

- Redmine 1.3.2 stable (MySql)
- Redmine Git Hosting Plugin 0.4.2

Comment: Do you mean the `gitolite.conf` file (published in your `.gitolite/conf` on the gitolite server) changes? and all the `W+` are gone? Which gitolite are you using, btw? Gitolite V2 or V3?

Comment: I mean the gitolite.conf file available on the gitolite-admin repo and yes,everytime I run a git push, the W+ permissions are gone. I'm not quite sure about the gitolite version I'm using; what would be the preferable way to obtain that?

Comment: Do a simple ssh git@yourGitoliteServer, it should return a message from Gitolite (I assume you used git as a user for managing gitolite, if not, replace it with the appropriate account)

Comment: I had to use the option info in the ssh command you suggested: ssh git@host info. The gitolite version is 2.2-1 (Debian) and the git one is 1.7.9.5.

Comment: I think that this can also be useful: whenever I push a change to the gitolite remote repository, the message Repository does not have "hooks.redmine_gitolite.key" set. Skipping hook is prompted.

Comment: Ok try first to upgrade to a gitolite V3, and see if the issue persists

Comment: Already tried with gitolite v3 and the problem is still occurring!

Comment: Ok, then it is best to simplify the issue and get back to just one repo (the gitolite-admin) declared itself as RW+ by the gitolite-admin "account", and see if with just one repo, that is still there. Also make sure your project.list is there, see http://serverfault.com/questions/419102/gitweb-document-root-with-gitolite

Comment: The projects.list where supposed to be and the permissions of the gitolite-admin repo are never touched.